# What can we do for 6.9 million questions without any upvoted or accepted answers? When will it get to 7?

Tags: discussion

How should the original posters be "targetted" to upvote or accept an answer to questions they have asked?

1. not "upvoted or accepted" because they forgot - perhaps send warning they will have rep removed?
2. auto answer acceptance for "dormant" or "abandoned" accounts? Some original posters post a question and get one answer then never appear again, so they do not want to be "part" of the community.

Or should these "unvoted or accepted" question just be left to linger on?

What do you think? And other options can be suggested.

Asked because I saw this at the top of my page:

[image]

Comment: I mean, half of them have 0 answers at all, which I fail to see as being fixable by "targeting" the OPs

Comment: Why assume the answer is correct?  I've seen plenty of _terrible_ answers.  What problem does auto acceptance _actually_ solve?

Comment: How do you accept an answer on a question with 2 answers that are equally voted?

Comment: Most of the original posters are probably of the minimum effort type and ***nothing*** (short of fear (physical violence) or real monetary reward (of sufficient size)) can make them do anything.

Comment: I'm unconvinced of the usefulness of acceptance. It seems completely worthless, to me. So, to convince me that anything should be done about acceptance, I think you should put forward an argument that shows acceptance is not a mistake. And one that isn't an appeal to tradition "But we *have* acceptance*" because that's the mistake I'm talking about.

Comment: And how many of those millions of questions and answers actually hold value? This sounds like a symptom you're trying to wrap duct tape around not to fix it but so we don't see it anymore.

Comment: How many of those 6.9 million questions are older than a year?  Older than 3 years? older than 6 years?  At some point, if a question has zero attention pointed towards it then we can assume it's been abandoned. Your asking a good question but the wrong subset of questions.

Comment: @SecurityHound this is the motivation people provide... go figure - I just wanted to generate some possibilities to consider dealing with that increasing number of questions. Perhaps others won't try to contribute now either.

Comment: @SolarMike - What? I am just trying to focus attention on the questions being actively improved. I don't understand your last comment or how it's connected to other users contributing in the slighest.

Comment: *"...perhaps send warning they will have rep removed?"* But they won't have rep removed. The site doesn't punish people for not upvoting or accepting an answer; why would we want to threaten people with that?

Answer (score 22):

They're not upvoted or accepted because upvotes and acceptance are an indication that a human has found the answer useful.

Automatically accepting answers is the worst possible solution, because it would add the mark without a human ever checking if it's correct.  This isn't a help desk where we're closing out tickets.

People should upvote answers they find useful.  If they're not doing that, either they don't understand the system, or the answers aren't good.

Comment: "*either they don't understand the system, or the answers aren't good.*" or the answers are unfindable in the vast sprawling pool of other Q&As. Which doesn't necessarily reflect the quality of the answer, but the reachability of the information.

Answer (score 9):

There are primarily two things we can do:

1. Provide a good answer. If there are no upvoted or accepted answers then it means that the question is in need of a good answer that can be upvoted.
2. Reevaluate the question. Maybe it's unanswerable and should be closed instead. Or maybe a simple edit would make it clearer, which could attract good answers.

Of course, if there already is a good answer that never received any upvotes, you can upvote it. This would also solve the problem you are describing. However, even then, the two points above might still be applicable.

Comment: 2.1 If there are old comments preventing automatic removal, flag them for deletion.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Oh yeah, questions older than a year can be stopped from deletion by there being at least two comments on it. I didn't know/remember that. Seems like a fruitless criteria given that comments are readily and frequently abused.